# Preserving shape local convexity/concavity with Matlab interpolation

Tags: matlab, interpolation, spline

I am trying to interpolate an array of scattered values (asterisks in the plots). The algorithms that worked best so far are:

**Spline**

[image]

**pchip**

[image]

However, they both fail in preserving a natural trend of the curve between the 30° and 360° directions. The right approximation should be somewhere in between. As it is clear, the two different behaviors depend on the slope of the interpolated line right before the known values.

Is there some way to constrain the algorithm so that it doesn't show such an artificial trend?

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], in particular the input data and how to generate your two examples...

Comment: I'm assuming that this might be due to the lack of periodicity condition. Did you try adding the data point for 330° also as -30°, and similarly the data point for 30° as 390°?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "unwrap" your polar plot into a cartesian plot to better understand what's going on here. As shown below, the extrapolation to `0` and `360` degrees with `pchip` is very reasonable in x-y space given the inputs.

If you want to dictate the behaviour across the end points then you need to add artificial endpoints to the input data which force the interpolation to be cyclic.

i.e.

```
% Input points
a = 30:30:330;
b = [0.6, 0.8, 0.7, 0.3, 0.3, 0.0, 0.3, 0.3, 0.7, 0.8, 0.6];
% Extend the inputs by wrapping f(330deg)=f(-30deg), f(390deg)=f(30deg)
a_ext = [-30, a, 390]; 
b_ext = [b(end), b, b(1)];
% convert to radians    
a = deg2rad(a);
a_ext = deg2rad(a_ext);

figure();
% Polar plot
subplot(2,1,1)
polarplot( a, b, '.', 'markersize', 20 )
hold on
ainterp = linspace(0,2*pi,100);
polarplot( ainterp, pchip(a,b,ainterp), 'linewidth', 1 )
polarplot( ainterp, pchip(a_ext,b_ext,ainterp), 'k', 'linewidth', 1 )
rlim( [-0.2, 1] )
legend( {'Input points','pchip','pchip extended'} )
% Cartesian plot
subplot(2,1,2)
plot( rad2deg(a), b, '.', 'markersize', 20 )
hold on
plot( rad2deg(ainterp), pchip(a,b,ainterp), 'linewidth', 1.5 )
plot( rad2deg(ainterp), pchip(a_ext,b_ext,ainterp), 'k', 'linewidth', 1.5 )
ylim( [-0.2, 1] ); xlim( [0, 360] ); grid on
```

[image: plots]